# how can i embed youtube video to editor

Tags: php, youtube-api

how can i embed youtube video to my site using URL, not embed code, i dont want to use iframe.
is there any script in php? i want to paste youtube URL in my editor and play it.

and also, i need a script to cut a short text (teaser) at the end of a text, for example dot. not just like

> this is a short news i pas...

i want to be

> this is a short news i paste here...

i use `mb_str` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [embed without iframes](http://jajodia-saket.sjbn.co/2011/06/how-to-embed-youtube-with-logoless-player-without-any-youtube-logo-on-it/) like this:

```
<object width="516" height="387">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/8Qz1v9758W0?version=3&modestbranding=1"></param>
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/8Qz1v9758W0?version=3&modestbranding=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="516" height="387" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed>
</object>
```

Replace `8Qz1v9758W0` with the id of the video you would like to embed.

Regarding cutting text/showing more than a snippet, when you say you use `mb_str` I'm guessing you mean you have [Multibyte Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) and you want to change the way you cut them; check the documentation for [mb_strcut](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strcut.php).